# Formula to match dates in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

This may sound really simple but I need a formula that checks if one column's date is the same as another, and if so put 'true' or '1' or something. I tried =IF(H2=G2, "True", "False") but it does not work...

Comment: Do your cells contain dates or datetimes values?

Comment: I think just dates as they were copied and pasted in, like this 29/05/2014

Comment: Please approve the answer below and close your question....

Comment: @Prasanna It is not your position to instruct when an answer should be accepted. The OP will decide if the answer is the solution best for them.

Comment: @CharlieRB I missed adding the line "if it meets your requirement". Sorry. Anyways, I WILL insist any OP close the question if there is an acceptable answer to him/her. I see many brilliant answers to some very good questions as "not closed". P.S: __"Thanks Kai Zen that's the one :) –  Chango"__ Closed answers give more confidence for the future user when searching for a solution.

Comment: @Prasanna Understood. Please be careful how things are worded. "Closing" a question is very different than "accepting" a question on Super User. Closing is an action taken on questions which do not meet the criteria of this site, while accepting is to choose the answer that best helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
28-07-2014  29-07-2014  FALSE               
29-07-2014  29-07-2014  TRUE                
                       =IF(M10=N10,"TRUE","FALSE")
```

Check your date format is correct and matches your system settings.

Answer (score 0):

Since Excel stores dates as a number and dates and times as a number with decimals this might be a little more bullet proof in case your dates have times that aren't displaying:

```
=IF(INT(G3)=INT(H3),"True","False")
```

The "INT" takes just the integer portion of the date number and compares them thus ignore any decimals or times.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
    =VALUE(G3)=VALUE(H3)
```

This would then compare if they were stored as text values or date, or number.